# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon from within container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I run a container (cAdvisor) that needs to access the Docker Engine of the host.

When I run it as a service with the command line, everything works fine:

```
docker service create  --name cadvisor  
--network clusternetwork  -p 8080:8080 
--mount type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock,ro     
--mount type=bind,src=/,dst=/rootfs,ro        
--mount type=bind,src=/sys,dst=/sys,ro     
--mount type=bind,src=/var/lib/docker,dst=/var/lib/docker,ro     
gcr.io/google-containers/cadvisor:latest
```

But when I transpose the following service to a docker-compose file and run it using `docker stack deploy -c myCadvisor-compose.yml cAdvisor`, it doesn't work and I get the following error: **failed to get docker info: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?**

Here is my docker-compose file. Did I forget to transpose something from the above service call?

```
version: "3.7"

services:

    cadvisor:
            image: gcr.io/google-containers/cadvisor:latest
            ports:
                    - 8080:8080
            volumes:
                - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock,ro   
                - /:/rootfs,ro
                - /sys:/sys,ro
                - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker,ro
            networks:
                    - clusternetwork
networks:
  clusternetwork:
    external: true
```

Comment: try adding :ro instead of ,ro

Comment: @StefanAvramovic Yeah it was actually that simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code. The main issue is the "," you must put an":". RW or RO doesn't matter. In my case the working one looks like this:

```
volumes:
    - /:/rootfs:ro
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
    - /sys:/sys:ro
    - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
```

Cheers Jules